# How to use an insert statement in Oracle to insert into two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, sql-insert

I have two insert statements like below A and B. I need combine these two insert statement into one, like statement C. I don't like duplicate code for example the select part in statement A and B. What is the correct format for statement C? Please ignore dynamic query statement, because the real statement select part is very complex.

statement A:

```
insert into a
  (firstname, lastname)
  select t2.firstname, t3.lastname
    from t1, t2, t3
   where t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
     and t2.t2_id = t3.t2_id;
```

statement B:

```
insert into b
  (personid)
  select t1.personid
    from t1, t2, t3
   where t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
     and t2.t2_id = t3.t2_id;
```

statement C:

```
insert into a
  (firstname, lastname)
insert into b
  (personid)
  select t2.firstname, t3.lastname, t1.personid
    from t1, t2, t3
   where t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
     and t2.t2_id = t3.t2_id;
```

The real world original statement is like below:

```
procedure allo_recipient(p_all_id       number,
                         p_allo_type    varchar2,
                         p_step_no      number,
                         p_region       varchar2,
                         p_don_reg_code varchar2,
                         p_med_urgent   varchar2,
                         p_don_id       number,
                         p_abo_ic       varchar2,
                         p_multi_organ  varchar2) is
begin
  insert into all_pat_list
    (apl_id,
     all_id,
     prod_id,
     prior_seq_no,
     org_code,
     all_step_no,
     pat_id,
     pat_name,
     sex,
     dob,
     ped_ind,
     blood_typ,
     home_prov_code,
     home_town,
     org_code_registered,
     org_descrip_registered,
     hosp_id,
     mrn,
     oldr_code,
     current_wait_list_stat_code,
     init_wait_list_stat_date,
     dis_code_prim_diag,
     dis_code_sec_diag,
     cadaver_liv_ind,
     weight,
     height,
     abdom_girth,
     chest_circum,
     chest_vert_right,
     chest_vert_left,
     chest_transverse,
     cmv,
     ebv,
     hepatitis_b_surface_ant,
     hepatitis_c,
     prev_trnsplt_no,
     all_step_descrip,
     eff_date,
     hcv_rna,
     dsa_cur_unaccp1,
     dsa_acc_unaccp1,
     dsa_cur_indet1,
     dsa_acc_indet1,
     dsa_cur_unaccp2,
     dsa_acc_unaccp2,
     dsa_cur_indet2,
     dsa_acc_indet2,
     x_match_serum_date, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     x_match_b_cell_res_ind, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     x_match_t_cell_res_ind, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     current_pra, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     current_pra_date, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     peak_pra, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     peak_pra_date, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     kp_allocation_points,
     cpra) --to do: c_pra need be replaced with new one in furture.
  --3rd select: get all needed elements for all_pat_list
    select apl_seq.nextval apl_id,
           p_all_id all_id,
           prod_id,
           all_kp_prior_seq.nextval prior_seq_no,
           org_code,
           all_step_no,
           pat_id,
           pat_name,
           sex,
           dob,
           ped_ind,
           blood_typ,
           home_prov_code,
           home_town,
           org_code_registered,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_org_type_desc(org_code_registered) org_descrip_registered,
           hosp_id,
           mrn,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_oldr_code(hosp_id) oldr_code,
           current_wait_list_stat_code,
           list_date init_wait_list_stat_date,
           dis_code_prim_diag,
           dis_code_sec_diag,
           cadaver_liv_ind,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_weight(pat_id) weight,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_height(pat_id) height,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_abdom_girth(pat_id) abdom_girth,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_chest_circum(pat_id) chest_circum,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_chest_vr(pat_id) chest_vert_right,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_chest_vl(pat_id) chest_vert_left,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_chest_trans(pat_id) chest_transverse,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'CMV') cmv,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'EBV') ebv,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'HBSAG') hepatitis_b_surface_ant,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'HCV') hepatitis_c,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_prev_tx_count(pat_id, org_code) prev_trnsplt_no, --tttt_gen_pkg.get_prev_tx_count(pat_id, 1) prev_trnsplt_no,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_all_step_descrip(p_step_no, org_code) all_step_descrip, --tttt_gen_pkg.get_all_step_descrip(p_step_no, 1) all_step_descrip,
           sysdate,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'HCV_RNA') hcv_rna,
           null dsa_cur_unaccp1,
           null dsa_acc_unaccp1,
           null dsa_cur_indet1,
           null dsa_acc_indet1,
           null dsa_cur_unaccp2,
           null dsa_acc_unaccp2,
           null dsa_cur_indet2,
           null dsa_acc_indet2,
           null x_match_serum_date,
           null x_match_b_cell_res_ind,
           null x_match_t_cell_res_ind,
           null current_pra,
           null current_pra_date,
           null peak_pra,
           null peak_pra_date,
           kp_allocation_points,
           cpra
      from (
            -- 1st select: get basic elements of pat list for each step
            select distinct prod.org_code,
                             p_step_no all_step_no,
                             p.pat_id,
                             p.last_name || ', ' || p.first_name || ' ' ||
                             p.middle_name pat_name,
                             p.sex,
                             p.dob,
                             decode(sign(months_between(sysdate, p.dob) / 12 - 18), -1, 'P', 'A') ped_ind,
                             p.blood_typ,
                             pr.prov_code_home home_prov_code,
                             pr.home_town,
                             pr.org_code org_code_registered,
                             pr.hosp_id,
                             pr.mrn,
                             tttt_gen_pkg.get_current_wls_code(prod_id) current_wait_list_stat_code,
                             tttt_gen_pkg.get_initial_wls_date(prod.prod_id) list_date, --init_wait_list_stat_date
                             dis_code_prim_diag,
                             dis_code_sec_diag,
                             cadaver_liv_ind,
                             pr.patr_id,
                             prod.prod_id,
                             tttt_kp_allocation.allocation_points(pr.patr_id, prod.org_code) kp_allocation_points,
                             null cpra
              from pat p, temp_kp_pat_pool pr, pat_register_org_det prod
             where p.pat_id = pr.pat_id
               and pr.patr_id = prod.patr_id
               and (p_allo_type, prod.org_code) in
                   (('K', '3'), ('K', '6'), ('P', '6')) -- ('K' => K; K/P; P) ('P' => K/P; P )

               and (pr.patr_id not in
                   (select patr_id from temp_kp_used_patrid_pool)) -- filter out patr_id(s) which has been handled in previous steps

               and pr.cadaver_liv_ind in ('B', 'D') --waiting for deceased and both.

               and (((p_region = 'L') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_prov_code(pr.hosp_id) = 'ON') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_oldr_code(pr.hosp_id) =
                   p_don_reg_code)) or

                   ((p_region = 'O') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_prov_code(pr.hosp_id) = 'ON') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_oldr_code(pr.hosp_id) !=
                   p_don_reg_code)) or

                   ((p_region = 'P') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_prov_code(pr.hosp_id) = 'ON')) or

                   --((p_region = 'H') and
                   --(tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_prov_code(pr.hosp_id) != 'ON') and
                   --(tttt_gen_pkg.is_hsp_pat = 'Y')) or -- to do: need pat HSP flag to identify pat belongs to HSP

                   ((p_region = 'NA') and (1 = 1)))

               and (((p_med_urgent = 'Y') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_current_wls_code(prod.prod_id) = 'H')) or

                   ((p_med_urgent = 'NA') and (1 = 1)))

               and (((p_abo_ic = 'PI') and
                   (tttt_kp_allocation.kp_abo_c_i(p_don_id, pr.pat_id) = 'PI')) or

                   ((p_abo_ic = 'I') and
                   (tttt_kp_allocation.kp_abo_c_i(p_don_id, pr.pat_id) = 'I')) or

                   ((p_abo_ic = 'C') and
                   (tttt_kp_allocation.kp_abo_c_i(p_don_id, pr.pat_id) = 'C')) or

                   ((p_abo_ic = 'NA') and (1 = 1)))

               and (((p_multi_organ = 'Y') and
                   (pr.org_code in (10, 14, 15))) or

                   ((p_multi_organ = 'NA') and (1 = 1)))

             order by kp_allocation_points desc, cpra desc, list_date -- end of 1st select
            ); --end of 2rd select
```

The real world modified statement using "Ed Gibbs" solution is like below, but unfortunately I got compile error :

"Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY tttt.tttt_KP_ALLOCATION

Error: PL/SQL: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
Line: 636
Text: all_kp_prior_seq.nextval prior_seq_no,

Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line: 574
Text: insert all into all_pat_list values

Error: Hint: Parameter 'p_loc_pro' is declared but never used in 'run_kp_allo'
Line: 847
Text: p_loc_pro   varchar2,
"

```
procedure allo_recipient(p_all_id       number,
                         p_allo_type    varchar2,
                         p_step_no      number,
                         p_region       varchar2,
                         p_don_reg_code varchar2,
                         p_med_urgent   varchar2,
                         p_don_id       number,
                         p_abo_ic       varchar2,
                         p_multi_organ  varchar2) is
begin
  insert all into all_pat_list values
    (apl_id,
     all_id,
     prod_id,
     prior_seq_no,
     org_code,
     all_step_no,
     pat_id,
     pat_name,
     sex,
     dob,
     ped_ind,
     blood_typ,
     home_prov_code,
     home_town,
     org_code_registered,
     org_descrip_registered,
     hosp_id,
     mrn,
     oldr_code,
     current_wait_list_stat_code,
     init_wait_list_stat_date,
     dis_code_prim_diag,
     dis_code_sec_diag,
     cadaver_liv_ind,
     weight,
     height,
     abdom_girth,
     chest_circum,
     chest_vert_right,
     chest_vert_left,
     chest_transverse,
     cmv,
     ebv,
     hepatitis_b_surface_ant,
     hepatitis_c,
     prev_trnsplt_no,
     all_step_descrip,
     eff_date,
     hcv_rna,
     dsa_cur_unaccp1,
     dsa_acc_unaccp1,
     dsa_cur_indet1,
     dsa_acc_indet1,
     dsa_cur_unaccp2,
     dsa_acc_unaccp2,
     dsa_cur_indet2,
     dsa_acc_indet2,
     x_match_serum_date, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     x_match_b_cell_res_ind, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     x_match_t_cell_res_ind, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     current_pra, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     current_pra_date, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     peak_pra, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     peak_pra_date, -- to do: this field is use by old allocation report, it need determine keep or discard in the new report
     kp_allocation_points,
     cpra) --to do: c_pra need be replaced with new one in furture.
     into temp_kp_used_patrid_pool values (patr_id)
  --3rd select: get all needed elements for all_pat_list
    select apl_seq.nextval apl_id,
           p_all_id all_id,
           prod_id,
           all_kp_prior_seq.nextval prior_seq_no,
           org_code,
           all_step_no,
           pat_id,
           pat_name,
           sex,
           dob,
           ped_ind,
           blood_typ,
           home_prov_code,
           home_town,
           org_code_registered,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_org_type_desc(org_code_registered) org_descrip_registered,
           hosp_id,
           mrn,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_oldr_code(hosp_id) oldr_code,
           current_wait_list_stat_code,
           list_date init_wait_list_stat_date,
           dis_code_prim_diag,
           dis_code_sec_diag,
           cadaver_liv_ind,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_weight(pat_id) weight,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_height(pat_id) height,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_abdom_girth(pat_id) abdom_girth,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_chest_circum(pat_id) chest_circum,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_chest_vr(pat_id) chest_vert_right,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_chest_vl(pat_id) chest_vert_left,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_pat_chest_trans(pat_id) chest_transverse,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'CMV') cmv,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'EBV') ebv,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'HBSAG') hepatitis_b_surface_ant,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'HCV') hepatitis_c,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_prev_tx_count(pat_id, org_code) prev_trnsplt_no, --tttt_gen_pkg.get_prev_tx_count(pat_id, 1) prev_trnsplt_no,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_all_step_descrip(p_step_no, org_code) all_step_descrip, --tttt_gen_pkg.get_all_step_descrip(p_step_no, 1) all_step_descrip,
           sysdate,
           tttt_gen_pkg.get_latest_test_res(pat_id, 'HCV_RNA') hcv_rna,
           null dsa_cur_unaccp1,
           null dsa_acc_unaccp1,
           null dsa_cur_indet1,
           null dsa_acc_indet1,
           null dsa_cur_unaccp2,
           null dsa_acc_unaccp2,
           null dsa_cur_indet2,
           null dsa_acc_indet2,
           null x_match_serum_date,
           null x_match_b_cell_res_ind,
           null x_match_t_cell_res_ind,
           null current_pra,
           null current_pra_date,
           null peak_pra,
           null peak_pra_date,
           kp_allocation_points,
           cpra,
           patr_id
      from (
            -- 1st select: get basic elements of pat list for each step
            select distinct prod.org_code,
                             p_step_no all_step_no,
                             p.pat_id,
                             p.last_name || ', ' || p.first_name || ' ' ||
                             p.middle_name pat_name,
                             p.sex,
                             p.dob,
                             decode(sign(months_between(sysdate, p.dob) / 12 - 18), -1, 'P', 'A') ped_ind,
                             p.blood_typ,
                             pr.prov_code_home home_prov_code,
                             pr.home_town,
                             pr.org_code org_code_registered,
                             pr.hosp_id,
                             pr.mrn,
                             tttt_gen_pkg.get_current_wls_code(prod_id) current_wait_list_stat_code,
                             tttt_gen_pkg.get_initial_wls_date(prod.prod_id) list_date, --init_wait_list_stat_date
                             dis_code_prim_diag,
                             dis_code_sec_diag,
                             cadaver_liv_ind,
                             pr.patr_id,
                             prod.prod_id,
                             tttt_kp_allocation.allocation_points(pr.patr_id, prod.org_code) kp_allocation_points,
                             null cpra
              from pat p, temp_kp_pat_pool pr, pat_register_org_det prod
             where p.pat_id = pr.pat_id
               and pr.patr_id = prod.patr_id
               and (p_allo_type, prod.org_code) in
                   (('K', '3'), ('K', '6'), ('P', '6')) -- ('K' => K; K/P; P) ('P' => K/P; P )

               and (pr.patr_id not in
                   (select patr_id from temp_kp_used_patrid_pool)) -- filter out patr_id(s) which has been handled in previous steps

               and pr.cadaver_liv_ind in ('B', 'D') --waiting for deceased and both.

               and (((p_region = 'L') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_prov_code(pr.hosp_id) = 'ON') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_oldr_code(pr.hosp_id) =
                   p_don_reg_code)) or

                   ((p_region = 'O') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_prov_code(pr.hosp_id) = 'ON') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_oldr_code(pr.hosp_id) !=
                   p_don_reg_code)) or

                   ((p_region = 'P') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_prov_code(pr.hosp_id) = 'ON')) or

                   --((p_region = 'H') and
                   --(tttt_gen_pkg.get_hosp_prov_code(pr.hosp_id) != 'ON') and
                   --(tttt_gen_pkg.is_hsp_pat = 'Y')) or -- to do: need pat HSP flag to identify pat belongs to HSP

                   ((p_region = 'NA') and (1 = 1)))

               and (((p_med_urgent = 'Y') and
                   (tttt_gen_pkg.get_current_wls_code(prod.prod_id) = 'H')) or

                   ((p_med_urgent = 'NA') and (1 = 1)))

               and (((p_abo_ic = 'PI') and
                   (tttt_kp_allocation.kp_abo_c_i(p_don_id, pr.pat_id) = 'PI')) or

                   ((p_abo_ic = 'I') and
                   (tttt_kp_allocation.kp_abo_c_i(p_don_id, pr.pat_id) = 'I')) or

                   ((p_abo_ic = 'C') and
                   (tttt_kp_allocation.kp_abo_c_i(p_don_id, pr.pat_id) = 'C')) or

                   ((p_abo_ic = 'NA') and (1 = 1)))

               and (((p_multi_organ = 'Y') and
                   (pr.org_code in (10, 14, 15))) or

                   ((p_multi_organ = 'NA') and (1 = 1)))

             order by kp_allocation_points desc, cpra desc, list_date -- end of 1st select
            ); --end of 2rd select
```

Comment: you can use the `INSERT ALL` statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Sebas said above, `INSERT ALL` is the answer. Your "statement A" and "statement B" merged with `INSERT ALL` would look like this:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO a VALUES (firstname, lastname)
  INTO b VALUES (personid)
select t2.firstname, t3.lastname, t1.personid
  from t1, t2, t3
 where t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
   and t2.t2_id = t3.t2_id
```

Also, as HLGEM pointed out, implicit joins are generally frowned upon nowadays. Here's how to do it with ANSI-style joins:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO a VALUES (firstname, lastname)
  INTO b VALUES (personid)
SELECT t2.firstname, t3.lastname, t1.personid
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.t2_id = t3.t2_id
```

Comment: Do not encourage the use of the SQL antipattern of implict joins.

Comment: @HLGEM - you're right. I always use ANSI joins in my own code, but when I answer questions I tend to leave the joins as they were in the OP's example. I'll edit the response.

Comment: @HLGEM - modifications made, and thanks. I take your point - implicit joins are near the top of my "don't like" list (followed closely by gratiuitous aliasing) - but note that my original answer does accomplish what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: @EdGibbs and Sebas - never knew about INSERT ALL.  Thanks!  I learned something useful today!

Comment: @Ed Gibbs Hi "Ed Gibbs", Thanks for your solution, but unfortunately I modified my the statement using your way, I got compiled error. Please see my modified post.

Comment: @Matthew - I'm afraid you've run up against an Oracle limitation: Oracle doesn't support sequences in subqueries, and with `INSERT ALL` your query is considered a subquery. There's more about the ORA-02287 error [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287). Since you're already using a procedure, your best bet is to make your select statement a cursor, then loop through the cursor and add rows using individual `SELECT` statements. That would still be in line with your not wanting to repeat the `SELECT` statement - and now that you've published the `SELECT` I can see why :)

Comment: @Ed Gibbs, I have concern on cursor loop performance compare with two single insert statement with duplicate from & where section. So, which performance is better?

Comment: @Matthew - I'm afraid I don't know which will be slower. A lot will depend on how many rows your `SELECT` will get versus how optimized it is. If it's not very fast then better to run it just once. If it's pretty fast then it depends on how many rows it returns. Is there a reasonable upper limit on how many rows you expect to get? And if your query is at least "pretty fast" you may be able to turn it into a view and do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`  (rather than `INSERT ALL`) for both tables based on the view.